# wordpress wp_query using 's' => 'value'

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following wp query:

```
$keyword = $_GET['se'];
$args = array(  
             's' => $keyword,  
             'post_type' => 'page',  
             'posts_per_page' => '10',  
             'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'Active','value' => 'yes'  ),  
                          array('key' => '_wp_page_template','value' => 'default'  )  
                               ),  
             'orderby' => 'post_date',  
             'order' => 'DESC',  
             'showposts' => -1,  
             'paged' => $paged  
            );
   $qu = new WP_Query($args);  
while ( $qu->have_posts() ) :  
   $qu->the_post();  

       the_title();   
       the_excerpt();  

endwhile;  

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

If I don't include 's' => $keyword, it returns what you would expect but as soon as I include said keyword it returns nothing. The keyword does have matches in the DB.
Anyone know why? And where am I going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure $_GET['se'] has a value.

Comment: It certainly does have echoed the varible just to be safe.

Comment: Use Wordpresses debugging functionality to display the the generated query, and execute that query against your database. We can be fairly confident that the condition added by `'s' => $keyword` causes the query to match no rows, and seeing the query may help to resolve why.

Comment: hmm  SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (wp_posts.ID = '1353') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC   if I remove the keyword this output remains the same but posts are displayed. I used  echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request;

Comment: try to get the post that match the search query $query = new WP_Query( 's=$keyword' ); by itself this should give you some results so we can isolate the problem

Comment: seem whatever key word I use I get:  SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (wp_posts.ID = '1353') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC  this is using $qu = new WP_Query('s=$keyword');

Comment: post id 1353 is the id of the host page.

Comment: $qu->request, I get: caseSELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'closed' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'hidden') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Active' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'yes') AND (mt1.meta_key = '_wp_page_template' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'default') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date

Comment: But with s=$keyword I get: SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=2 ..I just don't get it?

Comment: It seems it was a plugin to blame namely: Relevanssi, disableing the plugin made my query work. Thanks anyway

Comment: thats why "global" influencer sucks... global variables, global hook-s...